# CodeIgniter 2.1.1 .htaccess issue after upgrade

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

I've had a client website using CodeIgniter 1.7 for about 6 years now with no issues. However, recently I updated the CodeIgniter framework to 2.1.1 and now the .htaccess is having issues. I've confirmed in the logs that it isn't getting to my controller so I believe this to be purely an .htaccess issue.

I've got several typical URL patterns:

```
mysite.com/<page name here>, i.e. mysite.com/faq  
mysite.com/admin/<action here>, i.e. mysite.com/admin/login
```

My `.htaccess` is currently:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/page/id/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(admin/*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, as should be apparent, `mysite.com/faq` should be rewritten to `mysite.com/page/id/faq`, but it is throwing a 404 instead.

Just going to `mysite.com` successfully loads the default controller, in this case the home page or the equivalent to `mysite.com/home`. All of the admin urls are working perfectly. `mysite.com/page/id/<page name here>` is also working perfectly.

Just for comparison, the original `.htaccess` that has worked fine for 6 years until I upgraded CodeIgniter was:

```
RewriteRule ^((images|styles|scripts|documents)/*.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(admin/*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page/id/$1
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This original one has the exact same behavior as the one I am currently trying to use above. The rewrite log for the original is as follows:

```
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/faq' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/faq' pattern='^application.*' => not-matched
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^((images|styles|scripts|documents)/*.*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(admin/*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] rewrite 'faq' -> 'page/id/faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add per-dir prefix: page/id/faq -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/page/id/faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/page/id/faq -> page/id/faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'page/id/faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='page/id/faq' pattern='!^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)' => matched
[rid#1db5120/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] rewrite 'page/id/faq' -> 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#1db5120/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/page/id/faq -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip document_root prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> /jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1db5120/initial] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] internal redirect with /jb2/index.php/page/id/faq [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq' pattern='^application.*' => not-matched
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^((images|styles|scripts|documents)/*.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(admin/*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='index.php/page/id/faq' pattern='!^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)' => not-matched
[rid#4f657d8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] pass through C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php
```

The rewrite log for the current `.htaccess` I've been trying is this:

```
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/faq' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/faq' pattern='^application.*' => not-matched
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq -> faq
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'faq'
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq' pattern='!-f' => matched
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/jb2/faq' pattern='!-d' => matched
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] rewrite 'faq' -> 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/page/id/faq -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (2) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip document_root prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> /jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#4fb2e70/initial] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] internal redirect with /jb2/index.php/page/id/faq [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq' pattern='^system.*' => not-matched
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq' pattern='^application.*' => not-matched
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php -> C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php/page/id/faq -> index.php/page/id/faq
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] applying pattern '^(admin/*)$' to uri 'index.php/page/id/faq'
[rid#1da50a0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/jb2/] pass through C:/wamp/www/jb2/index.php
```

The actual upgrade process was JUST on the CodeIgniter framework and reorganizing the files into the separate `application` and `system` folders, none of my actual custom code was touched other than the minimal changes that were required as part of the upgrade process.

I've tried about a billion different `.htaccess` command combos trying to get this thing to work and just can't get both the "normal" pages and the admin pages to load correctly with the same config. Ultimately my question is why did upgrading CodeIgniter magically break the URL rewriting, but I'd be more than happy to simply have this working again.

Does anyone have suggestions? I'd love another set of eyes on this.

Comment: Why not use routes instead of relying on htaccess? Do you want me to write the routes (ie. if u dont know)

Comment: I had the same problem a few hours ago.  The immediate workaround was to not upgrade until I can resolve this.  Have you redefined how the URLs work?  I am used to sitename.com/classfilename/method.

Comment: @wallyk Yeah I tried upgrading this site about a year ago and ran into the same issue and put off the upgrade, but now I've gotten everything working except the `/<page name>` to `/page/id/<page name>` rewrite to work so I'd really like to just get this working.

Comment: @KarmicDice I was under the impression that routes were not recommended. Like I said, it's been a number of years since I last touched the site because it's been super stable, so I'll have to revisit the route documentation and give it a try because this `.htaccess` voodoo is a pain in my rear.

Comment: Routes vs htaccess is same as fat models skinny controllers vs fat controllers skinny models... Controversial! But, if routes killed the sophistication of MVC, not all would implement it ;) Use routes, save your time ! :)

Comment: @KarmicDice, I just took out the `.htaccess` rules and added routes into the routes config file and none of them have any effect. Loading the root directory loads the default controller but specifying anything in the URL other than root gets a 404. The CI documentation doesn't mention any other changes that are necessary, am I missing something?

Comment: I am quite sure you are not missing anything. How about this.... You edit your question and put your directory structure. ALso, put what kind of routes you want for what controllers/actions. Accordingly, I will draft an answer with routes code. Sounds good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got it working with a suggestion from another forum. I changed `$config[‘uri_protocol’]` from `AUTO` to `PATH_INFO` and it magically worked. I did have to add a line to handle the `admin/*` URL format though, so my final `.htaccess` is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(admin/*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page/id/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your .htaccess file in the correct folder? CodeIgniter uses several .htaccess files, I believe the one inside of System and Application say Deny From All and the one above that has your rules in it.

Comment: Yeah, definitely editing the correct `.htaccess` at the root.